# ASP Chart - remove unwanted values which are appended to X axis

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have created a simple ASP chart which is displaying a date range (a week) in days on the X axis, and an integer value on Y axis.

I have created a datasource to pull the data, which currently returns this data (forgive the formatting, there are two columns, Date and Value)...

- Date value
- 24/04/2013 9
- 25/04/2013 10
- 26/04/2013 7
- 27/04/2013 12
- 28/04/2013 13
- 29/04/2013 10
- 30/04/2013 1

However when the chart renders, it is appending a day to both the beginning and end of the X axis - Resulting in the dates 22/04/2013 and 1/05/2013 appearing and my x-axis data series. My datasource does not mention anything apart from the data quoted above.

How can I remove the two appended days from the beginning and end of the chart?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found the answer! 

Under the property "ChartArea" > "Axis" > Change "IsMarginVisable" to false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!

Under the property "ChartArea" > "Axis" > Change "IsMarginVisable" to false...